# Markdown image titles

Tags: image, markdown

I have a simple markdown file containing an image:

```markdown
![image](MyLovelyImage.png "some title")
```

I'm using the GitHub viewer and there I see the image fine, but *without* the title / caption.
Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Markdown's link / image titles aren't the same as captions, and Markdown itself has no support for captions.

However, since [Markdown supports inline HTML](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html), you can caption images using [`<figure>` and `<figcaption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure).

Here is an example from the previous MDN link:

```html
<figure>
  <img
  src="https://developer.mozilla.org/static/img/favicon144.png"
  alt="The beautiful MDN logo.">
  <figcaption>MDN Logo</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like HTML in Markdown. This is why here an idea to solve it with plain markdown. The markdown (set two `css-classes` to the `p`-wrapper) and the `logo_caption` inside the `p`-wrapper. `Title` and `Alt` were already there.

```markdown
{: .cssclass1 .cssclass2 }
![Logo](/assets/img/logo.jpg "Logo title")
*logo_caption*
```

Output as HTML

```html
<p class="cssclass1 cssclass2">
  <img src="/assets/img/logo.jpg" alt="Logo" title="Logo title">
  <em>logo_caption</em>
</p>
```

The styling can be done in CSS.

Tested in jekyll v4.2 and kramdown.

Comment: (a) [HTML as been a first-class citizen in Markdown from the very beginning](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html). You might not _like_ it, but is part of the underlying design philosophy. (b) That `{: .class}` syntax is meaningless in Markdown. It _might_ mean something in a particular tool, or using a particular extension. But you can't just drop that into an arbitrary Markdown file and expect it to do something. (c) Paragraphs and emphasis are poor semantics here. Inline HTML allows us to choose tags that are much more appropriate.